# Encryption code segment which I do not understand

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am reading about encryption and having a lot of difficulty understanding these 3 Java statements of an encryption program.

```
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes())
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Maybe you should start by telling us what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questionas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Get a [Cipher object](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) that can encrypt/decrypt using the [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) algorithm. Java's cryptography code is a bit weird - instead of directly creating objects, you generally use a *getInstance* call with a String argument. (Note that "cipher" means "way of encrypting something".)

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
```

[Tell](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init%28int,%20java.security.Key%29) the cipher that you would like to encrypt something (Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE), and give it the encryption [key](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Key.html) *skeyspec*.

```
encrypted = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes())
```

The way ciphers work is that you feed them chunks of byte data using the *update* method, which causes the cipher to accumulate the encrypted data within itself. For the final block of data, *doFinal* is used, which tells the cipher that the encryption process is done. A different method is needed because the cipher often has to pad out the data returned to a particular length. *doFinal* then returns the final bit of encrypted information.

However, if there is a single readily available chunk of data, you can just call *doFinal* and it will give you all the encrypted bytes at once. But this explains why the method is called *doFinal*, not say, "*process*".

So in summary, the code above creates an AES encryption engine, gives it an encryption key, then uses it to encrypt the String *str* into the byte array *encrypted*.

Note that cryptography is very tricky business and very easy to get wrong. There's all kinds of things you need warning about that I haven't touched on because my wrists hurt now. So I would heavily recommend you get a copy of [Beginning Cryptography with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764596330) - it's where I learned to understand this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

In simpler terms,

> - create a new Encrypting Device using the AES algorithm;
> - make it ready
> - get the bytes of the string `str` and encrypt them; return the result into the `encrypted` object, whatever that is.

what exactly did you not understand?